# How to Fix this Error "A generic error occurred in GDI+"?

Tags: c#, image, save, picturebox

Open An Image from default name and save it by default name.(overwrit it)

I need make graphics from Image("Default.jpg") that put it on picturebox1.image and draw some graphic on picurebox1.(it works and it is not my problem) But I can't save picturebox1.Image overwrite on "Default.jpg"(this is My problem).If I change the save name it work but I need to overwrite it and open it manytimes.
Thank You

```
    Boolean Play = false;
    Pen P = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
    Graphics Temp;
    int X1, X2, Y1, Y2;
    Image Default_Image = new Bitmap("Default.jpg");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Temp = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    }
    private void PictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Play)
        {
            X2 = e.X;
            Y2 = e.Y; ;
            Temp.DrawLine(P, X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
            pictureBox1.Image.Save("Default.jpg");
            Play = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Default_Image = new Bitmap("Default.jpg");
            Temp = Graphics.FromImage(Default_Image);
            pictureBox1.Image =Default_Image;
            X1 = e.X;
            Y1 = e.Y;
            Play = true;
        }
    }
```

{"A generic error occurred in GDI+."}

Comment: If you're never disposing of the `Bitmap` that owns your newly created 'Default.jpg', then it likely still has the file open when you're attempting to save. The GDI wrapping libraries do not give particularly helpful exception messages.

Comment: Yes,I think I need a code to close the file before saving.I dispose and save it but saved without graphic.I try dispose but didnt work right.I try to save picturebox1.image in default_image but changed graphic not saved as image.forgive me for bad english writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **overwrite** an image you need to make sure **no** connections remain to it. `Closing`, `Disposing` or `Cloning` are not quite enough...

Here is a function that creates a truly independent copy:

```
Bitmap GetClone(string imageName)
{
    if (!File.Exists(imageName)) return null;
    Bitmap bmp2 = null;
    using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(imageName))
    {
        bmp2 = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, bmp.PixelFormat);
        bmp2.SetResolution(bmp.HorizontalResolution, bmp.VerticalResolution);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2))
        {
            g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    return bmp2;
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
string file = yourImageFileName;
Bitmap bmp = GetClone(file);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    // draw what you want..
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 11, 11, 199, 199);
}
bmp.Save(file, ImageFormat.Png);  // use your own format etc..
```

You should also take care to not leak old `PictureBox.Image` versions.. Here is a helper function:

```
void SetPBoxImage(PictureBox pbox, Bitmap bmp)
{
    Bitmap dummy = (Bitmap)pbox.Image;
    pbox.Image = null;
    if (dummy != null) dummy.Dispose();
    pbox.Image = bmp;
}
```

Comment: Doubtful. How did you use the code? Note that you __must not read__ the target file!

Comment: Did you get it to work now? - Note that the way you are handling the drawing is not recommended!

Comment: What you mean I should not read the target file?  I use "bitmap bmp=new btimap(string filename);"

Comment: I mean what I wrote. Instead of `bitmap bmp=new btimap(string filename);` use `Bitmap bmp = GetClone(file);` !